# c++: exception error after closing console app

Tags: c++, binary, ifstream, ofstream

I am in the process of learning c++ and have a question regarding reading and writing objects to files.

I created a class called Person. In my main file I created two instances of the Person class. I write instance one to a file called "person.dat" and later read it back into the second instance I created. Everything is working as expected except that there is an exception that is thrown after the program closes. I am not sure why or what is causing it.

> Exception: *Unhandled exception at 0x55ABDF62 (msvcp120d.dll) in
>   Writing Binary Objects.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing
>   location 0xFEEEFEEE.*

Can anybody shed some light on this for me?

Code: Person.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person {
    private:
        string name;
        string surname;
        int age;
    public:
        Person();
        Person(string, string, int);
        void setName(string);
        void setSurname(string);
        void setAge(int);
        string getName();
        string getSurname();
        int getAge();
};

Person::Person() {}

Person::Person(string _name, string _surname, int _age) {
    setName(_name);
    setSurname(_surname);
    setAge(_age);
}

void Person::setName(string _name) {
    name = _name;
}

void Person::setSurname(string _surname) {
    surname = _surname;
}

void Person::setAge(int _age) {
    age = _age;
}

string Person::getName() {
    return name;
}

string Person::getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

int Person::getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

Code: Program.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //create person 1
    Person person;
    person.setName("Kobus");
    person.setSurname("Beets");
    person.setAge(24);

    //write person 1 to file
    ofstream out;
    out.open("person.dat", ios::binary);    
    out.write(reinterpret_cast <char *> (&person), sizeof(person));
    out.close();    

    //create person 2
    Person person2;
    person2.setName("John");
    person2.setSurname("Doe");
    person2.setAge(26);    

    //read person 1 from file into person 2
    ifstream in;
    in.open("person.dat", ios::binary);
    in.read(reinterpret_cast <char *> (&person2), sizeof(person2));
    in.close();

    //print new person 2
    cout << " " << person2.getName() << " " << person2.getSurname() << " is " << person2.getAge() << " year(s) old... \n\n ";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that under Windows there are Structured Exceptions (SEH - structured exception handling), that is what you see here. They are different from C++ exceptions

Comment: It makes a lot more sense now. Thank you. I didn't even know it could happen on that level. I guess there is a first time for everything. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly write objects to a file in this way, unless you have a POD-style data structures (e.g. just simple C data types or a struct/class thereof, no pointers, no C++ data types).

In your case, Person has two std::string members, which itself contain pointers and other stuff, which will loose its meaning once written to file and re-read to memory.

You would need to add some more logic to write the actual string contents (see std::string::c_str(), std::string::data(), std::string::size()).

The exception is probably causes by the std::string desctructor, which tries to free or access memory which is already freed.

Comment: I tested the same reading and writing methods with a simple struct which only has two int values in it and it seems to work without throwing that exception. Thanks for the info. I will have a look through the info you provided and see how I can use it in my programs. I definitely need to be able to write strings to binary files as well.

Comment: A simple struct with to ints would be POD and would not contain any pointer. You can have a look at the (somewhat obscure) source of std::string https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h. There is a member in line 114 _M_dataplus, which is actually a pointer - this will cause the problem here.

Comment: If you need to write the data, consider writing the length, followed by the data or something like that.

Comment: The provided link was actually the source for the GNU c++ library, but it will be similar for Microsoft/Visual Studio.